# Wikipedia Api in java

Tags: mediawiki

I am using wikipedia  api to get result as article for example to get result on INDIA **i`m using action=parse and page="INDIA"**
can anyone please tell me how to use this using java.
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The  [Java Wikipedia API (Bliki engine)](http://code.google.com/p/gwtwiki/) might help you, there are also [other options availible](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aClient_code#Java)